# should mongodb nodes in replicaset need to be time synchronized?

Tags: mongodb, replication

"MongoDB in Action" book says:

> Imagine you issue a write to the primary node of a replica set. What happens next? First, the write is recorded and then added to the
>   primary’s oplog. Meanwhile, all sec- ondaries have their own oplogs
>   that replicate the primary’s oplog. So when a given secondary node is
>   ready to update itself, it does three things. First, it looks at the
>   time- stamp of the latest entry in its own oplog. Next, it queries the
>   primary’s oplog for all entries greater than that timestamp. Finally,
>   it adds each of those entries to its own oplog and applies the entries
>   to itself

So this means nodes must be time synchronized? because timestamps must be equal on all nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, yes, it is a very good idea to have your hosts synchronized (NTP is the usual solution).  In fact I have seen far worse issues caused than an out of sync oplog - different times on database hosts in a cluster should be considered a must.

This is actually mentioned on the Production Notes page in the docs:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Production+Notes#ProductionNotes-Linux

See the note about minimizing clock skew.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the writing you have provided, nodes are basing everything on the timestamp of the most recently received write, not their own clocks. However, the problem happens when the master is stepped down and a secondary becomes the primary. If the time is skewed greatly, it may cause replication to be delayed or other issues.