# Should two identical databases, one acting as the single source of truth, be forced to have the same timestamps?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, database-design, architecture, distributed-system

I have two databases with virtually identical records, one acting as the single source of truth. The single source of truth regularly updates the other database so that they match.

I am wondering if the timestamps of each identical record should be forced to be the *same* between databases, or if I should allow each database to manage its own timestamps independently?

Are there any long-term pros or cons to identical timestamps, perhaps under the context of running helpful queries to maintain data integrity and uniformity should they get out of sync?

I am new to distributed systems, so thanks in advance for your patience and help.

Comment: "I am wondering if the timestamps of each identical record should be forced to be the same between databases, or if I should allow each database to manage its own timestamps independently?"

Why would you want this?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-architecture-geographically-distributed/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068761/should-mongodb-nodes-in-replicaset-need-to-be-time-synchronized

Answer (score 0):

@Danyolo - I suggest you take a look at MongoDB replicasets. MongoDB has a really neat replication system to ensure high availability and resiliency. Check out this link:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-architecture-geographically-distributed/